# why does NVIDIA-SMI Stops working mid task?

Tags: amazon-ec2, driver, nvidia, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running a compute heavy task with 4GPUs on AWS's G4DN instance running ubuntu 20.04 LTS. In the beginning NVIDIA-SMI works just fine. I am able to get all the info I need, but as time progresses, I get the following error.

```
NVIDIA-SMI couldn't find libnvidia-ml.so library in your system. Please make sure that the NVIDIA Display Driver is properly installed and present in your system.\nPlease also try adding directory that contains libnvidia-ml.so to your system PATH.\n"
```

Does anyone know what's happening? Is my operating system trying to update something that it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly missing `libnvidia-ml.so` which is typically in the `libnvidia-compute-xxx` package.

I used the following command to resolve the error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libnvidia-compute-XXX-server
```

Make sure to replace XXX with the version of the package you're using. You can check your version by running:

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```